# Rewriting rules with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Let's say I have two php files in my root directory (acceable from the internet): index.php and some.php. When someone goes to my site at mydomain.net I want them to be actually accessing some.php and any further path presented in the url would be sent to some.php as a GET value. How would I do this with .htaccess?

mydomain.net -> some.php

mydomain.net/index.php -> some.php?value=index.php

mydomain.net/somefolder/index.php -> some.php?value=somefolder/index.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some.php?value=$1
```